# How to access JSON object returned by Google Calendar Api

Tags: php, error-handling, exception, google-api, google-api-php-client

I am using this bit of code to catch Exceptions from the Google Calendar API

```
//authorize the client
      try{
          $client = $this->gcal_sync_auth($crm_user_id);
        }
      catch (Exception $ex) 
        {
      $message = $ex->getMessage();
      die("could not connect ". $message);
        }
```

The `$ex->getMessage()` works fine and returns the exception message as a string, but it is formatted as below.  I have never encountered an array like this. It looks like JSON but seems malformed.  How can I just access/print the "Invalid email or User ID" without the rest.

```
    Google_Auth_Exception Object
(
    [message:protected] => Error refreshing the OAuth2 token, message: '{
  "error" : "invalid_grant",
  "error_description" : "Invalid email or User ID"
}'
    [string:Exception:private] => 
    [code:protected] => 400
    [file:protected] => xxx/application/third_party/Google_API/src/Google/Auth/OAuth2.php
    [line:protected] => 364
    [trace:Exception:private] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [file] => xxx/application/third_party/Google_API/src/Google/Auth/OAuth2.php
                    [line] => 315
                    [function] => refreshTokenRequest
                    [class] => Google_Auth_OAuth2
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [grant_type] => assertion
                                    [assertion_type] => http://oauth.net/grant_type/jwt/1.0/bearer
                                    [assertion] =>
                                    [serviceAccountName] =>              xxxxx@xxxxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com
                                    [scopes] => https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar
                                    [privateKey] =>
```

Comment: Read error message and follow what it tells. Reset your outh2 key, write valid email

Comment: Thanks.  But did you even read my question?  I am trying to parse the exception message so I can print out something more intelligible to the end user.

Comment: what you getting if you do like this : print_r($ex);

Comment: The same thing but more arrays below it.

Comment: pls show full error array. did you get something like this : https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/errors

Comment: I just wanted to see what error code you are getting >

Comment: Ok I update the code above with the contents of the $ex var to the first index.

Comment: I can get  the whole message string with $ex->getMessage();  or I can get the error code with $ex->getCode();  But the Message string looks like it is in JSON.   But I can't find a way to just parse out the "error_description"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104255/discussion-between-monty-and-skribe).

Comment: Hope following links will help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9930843/get-string-within-protected-object
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20334355/how-to-get-protected-property-of-object-in-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the way I have this working now with the help of a friend. Hope it helps someone else. You can put it directly inline with your code as below or put it into a function to reuse it.

```
try{
    $client = $this->gcal_sync_auth($crm_user_id);
   }
 catch (Google_Auth_Exception $ex) {
    $parts = explode("'", $ex->getMessage());
     array_pop($parts);
     array_shift($parts);
    $error = json_decode(implode("'", $parts));
 }
```

Then you can access the `error_description` in the JSON with simply with

```
$error->error_description
```