# How to get protected property value of object in PHP

Tags: php, object

I have a object with protected property that I want to get `dateTime`.

```
1)modelData->start->dateTime //2017-05-10T17:00:00+05:30
2)modelData->end->dateTime //2017-05-10T17:20:00+05:30
```

The object looks like

```
Google_Service_Calendar_Event Object
(
    [collection_key:protected] => recurrence   
    [attachmentsType:protected] => Google_Service_Calendar_EventAttachment   
    [created] => 2017-05-08T07:05:43.000Z
    [creatorType:protected] => Google_Service_Calendar_EventCreator
    [creatorDataType:protected] => 
    [description] => 
    [endType:protected] => Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime
    [endDataType:protected] => 
    [endTimeUnspecified] => 
    [etag] => "2988454353000000"
    [extendedPropertiesType:protected] => Google_Service_Calendar_EventExtendedProperties
    [extendedPropertiesDataType:protected] => 
    [gadgetType:protected] => Google_Service_Calendar_EventGadget   
    [visibility] => 
    [internal_gapi_mappings:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [modelData:protected] => Array
        (
            [creator] => Array
                (
                    [email] => pickzy.nettest@gmail.com
                    [self] => 1
                )

            [organizer] => Array
                (
                    [email] => pickzy.nettest@gmail.com
                    [self] => 1
                )

            [start] => Array
                (
                    [dateTime] => 2017-05-10T17:00:00+05:30
                    [timeZone] => Asia/Calcutta
                )

            [end] => Array
                (
                    [dateTime] => 2017-05-10T17:20:00+05:30
                    [timeZone] => Asia/Calcutta
                )

            [reminders] => Array
                (
                    [useDefault] => 1
                )

        )

)
```

**PHP Script:**

I can get etag value without producted

```
echo "-----".$result->getEtag(); //"2988454353000000"
```

I cannot get start and end value with producted

```
echo "-----".$result = $event->getData(); //Error undefined method
```

**My Refer:**

[Get string within protected object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9930843/get-string-within-protected-object)

[How to get protected property of object in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20334355/how-to-get-protected-property-of-object-in-php)

Please advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Visibility](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php)

> Members declared protected can be accessed only within the class 
>   itself and by inheriting classes.

If you need to access the property from outside, pick one:
•Don't declare it as protected, make it public instead
•Write a couple of functions to get and set the value (getters and setters)

> If you don't want to modify the original class (because it's a
>   third-party library you don't want to mess) create a custom class that
>   extends the original one:

```
class My_Google_Service_Calender_Event extends Google_Service_Calendar_Event {
}
```

Comment: Assume `result` is an object. How to display?

Comment: $my_array =(array)$result;   var_dump($my_array);

Comment: My friend I think that you need to read this from php manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php