# wp_remote_post response body is protected

Tags: wordpress, api, http

I have made an API call with `wp_remote_post` and tried to retrieve the body with `wp_remote_retrieve_body`. But the response only showing headers and the body is protected.

below code, I have used to make an API call.

```
$args = array(
                'LocationId' => $loc_id,
                'AppId' => $app_id
               );
    $response = wp_remote_post( 'https://www.apiurl.com?APIKEY='."$api_key".'', $args );

$responceData = json_decode(wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response ), TRUE );
print_r($response);
```

and the printed response (just starting piece of data) is :

> Array ( [headers] => Requests_Utility_CaseInsensitiveDictionary Object ( [data:protected]

I am developing the wordpress plugin in localhost. How to solve this error.

Full Response :

```
Array ( [headers] => Requests_Utility_CaseInsensitiveDictionary Object ( [data:protected] => Array ( [cache-control] => no-cache, no-store [pragma] => no-cache [content-type] => application/json; charset=utf-8 [expires] => -1 [server] => Microsoft-IIS/10.0 [access-control-allow-origin] => * [x-aspnet-version] => 4.0.30319 [x-powered-by] => ASP.NET [date] => Fri, 13 Jul 2018 06:24:16 GMT [content-length] => 1858 ) ) [body] => {"Already10Questions":{"Count":1,"ResponseErrors":[{"Already10Questions":null,"AlreadyEmailErrorMessage":null,"AuthorizationError":null,"CaseNo":"[180712-23:24:16]_3D94D663C0DB","ErrorMessage":null,"SuccessMsg":null,"UserRegisterSuccessMsg":null}]},"AlreadyEmailErrorMessages":{"Count":1,"ResponseErrors":[{"Already10Questions":null,"AlreadyEmailErrorMessage":null,"AuthorizationError":null,"CaseNo":"[180712-23:24:16]_3D94D663C0DB","ErrorMessage":null,"SuccessMsg":null,"UserRegisterSuccessMsg":null}]},"AuthorizationError":{"Count":1,"ResponseErrors":[{"Already10Questions":null,"AlreadyEmailErrorMessage":null,"AuthorizationError":null,"CaseNo":"[180712-23:24:16]_3D94D663C0DB","ErrorMessage":null,"SuccessMsg":null,"UserRegisterSuccessMsg":null}]},"ErrorMessages":{"Count":1,"ResponseErrors":[{"Already10Questions":null,"AlreadyEmailErrorMessage":null,"AuthorizationError":null,"CaseNo":"[180712-23:24:16]_3D94D663C0DB","ErrorMessage":null,"SuccessMsg":null,"UserRegisterSuccessMsg":null}]},"ExistPhoneNumber":{"Count":1,"ResponseErrors":[{"Already10Questions":null,"AlreadyEmailErrorMessage":null,"AuthorizationError":null,"CaseNo":"[180712-23:24:16]_3D94D663C0DB","ErrorMessage":null,"SuccessMsg":null,"UserRegisterSuccessMsg":null}]},"SuccessMsg":{"Count":1,"ResponseErrors":[{"Already10Questions":null,"AlreadyEmailErrorMessage":null,"AuthorizationError":null,"CaseNo":"[180712-23:24:16]_3D94D663C0DB","ErrorMessage":null,"SuccessMsg":null,"UserRegisterSuccessMsg":null}]},"UserRegisterSuccessmessages":{"Count":1,"ResponseErrors":[{"Already10Questions":null,"AlreadyEmailErrorMessage":null,"AuthorizationError":null,"CaseNo":"[180712-23:24:16]_3D94D663C0DB","ErrorMessage":null,"SuccessMsg":null,"UserRegisterSuccessMsg":null}]},"CheckUserLocationAccessByLocationIdList":null,"ItemsCount":0,"RestaurantTotalCountByFilterList":null,"appDetails":null}
```

**UPDATE: Problem is solved with the below code. In my understanding, the problem is with sending arguments to the API in a wrong way.**  **Thanks For Helping [Sally Cj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9217760/sally-cj)**

```
$postData = array(
    'LocationId' => $loc_id,
    'AppId' => $app_id,
);
$context = array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'headers' => "Authorization:\r\n".
            "Content-Type: application/json\r\n",
        'httpversion' => '1.0',
        'redirection' => 5,
        'timeout' => 60,
        'blocking' => true,
        'body' => json_encode($postData)
    );
            $response = wp_remote_post( 'apiurl.com?APIKEY='."$api_key".'', $context);
            $currency = wp_remote_post( 'apiurl.com?APIKEY='."$api_key".'', $context);

if ( is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
   $error_message = $response->get_error_message();
   echo "Something went wrong: $error_message";
} else {
    $responceData = json_decode(wp_remote_retrieve_body($response), true);
    $currencyData = json_decode(wp_remote_retrieve_body($currency), true);
```

Comment: Can you print `$response` ?

Comment: Array ( [headers] => Requests_Utility_CaseInsensitiveDictionary Object ( [data:protected]        <<<< this is the responce i have printed using `print_r ($response);`

Comment: @SudharshanNair are you asking for full response???

Comment: Can you also post Full response in question itself ?

Comment: @SudharshanNair I have Updated Full response.

Comment: Can you have a  look at this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9930843/get-string-within-protected-object

Comment: `function getData()
{
  return $response;
} $responceData = getData(); `   Is this how I need to change.

Comment: Try Reflection  part

Comment: I have tried the reflection and many methods which are available in stackoverflow on how to get protected data from an array, still didn't worked. Can you explain me what actually happens with reflection.

Comment: The "protected body" is *not* the response body. Instead, it's a `protected` property of the [`Requests_Utility_CaseInsensitiveDictionary` class](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/requests_utility_caseinsensitivedictionary/) instance. The actual body is in `$response['body']` - try to `echo` it and you'd see the raw response body.

Comment: But you should *use the `wp_remote_retrieve_body()` function to retrieve the response body*. And actually, you've already done that - see the `$responceData = ...` in your question. So with that variable, you could do `echo $responceData['ItemsCount'];` or `var_dump( $responceData )` to see the *array*'s items.

Comment: var_dump($responceData) is giving the same output which i have ipdated in the question

Comment: I was referring to `$responceData = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response ), TRUE ); var_dump( $responceData );` try once more.

Comment: var_dump($responceData) returns first level array only. I have made same API call with PHP method file_get_contents and received multi dimentional array. Where is the problem???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### The Problem

It's *not* about the response body being "protected". But you're not getting the expected response *data* because the *request* body was *incomplete* — i.e. it did *not* contain the data in `$args` (e.g. `AppId`).

Because `$args` is the *request* body; so it should be passed to `wp_remote_post()` like this:

```
$response = wp_remote_post( 'https://www.apiurl.com?APIKEY='."$api_key".'', array(
    'body' => $args
) );
```

See https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_remote_post#Parameters

### The Fixed Code

*(Re-indented for clarity; and there were also other changes)*

```
// Request body.
$body = array(
    'LocationId' => $loc_id,
    'AppId'      => $app_id
);
$response = wp_remote_post( 'https://www.apiurl.com?APIKEY='."$api_key".'', array(
    'body' => $body
) );

// Response body.
$body = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response );

// On success (i.e. `$body` is a valid JSON string), `$responceData` would be an
// `ARRAY`.
$responceData = ( ! is_wp_error( $response ) ) ? json_decode( $body, true ) : null;
var_dump( $responceData );
```

### Additional Note

Here, `$responceData` would be an `array` because you set the *second* parameter to `true`:

```
$responceData = json_decode(wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response ), TRUE );
```

So if you wanted `$responceData` to be an `object`, then simply omit the second parameter:

```
$responceData = json_decode(wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response ) );
//$responceData = json_decode(wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response ), false ); // equivalent to above
```

See the [PHP manual for `json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) for further details.

Comment: The problem is solved with this [code] (https://pastebin.com/AT3XCziN) . Thank you so much for your response.

Comment: I guess yesterday I missed the `Content-Type: application/json` header.. but anyway, thanks also for accepting my answer. 